# Delphi 2009 IDE Structure View Collapse function

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2009

Does anyone know now to collapse all items in Delphi 2009 IDE structure View?

I have no idea to collapse all items and that make me hard to find my class from the view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select root node (Classes) and press / (divide sign) on the numerical keypad. That will collaps everything. Then press +  (plus) key on the numerical keypad and first level will expand.

You can also play with - (minus, collapses everything but + will expand everyhing, not only the first sublevel) and * (multiply, expands everything).

Left arrow key works the same as - and right arrow key works the same as +.

Those shortcuts work the same in Windows native tree control (for example the one in the Registry Editor) and are pretty much universally useful for Windows applications that are displaying tree structure.