# Delphi IDE Structure View - default to collapsed

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, delphi-10.4-sydney

The Delphi IDE: sometime after Delphi 7:

[image]

The *Structure Viewer* defaults to expanding all the nodes:

[image]

Which makes it inherently non-useful for viewing the structure.

Does anyone know of a way to default the Delphi **Structure Viewer** so it defaults the nodes to collapsed?

## Bonus Reading

- [Delphi 2009 IDE Structure View Collapse function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480216/delphi-2009-ide-structure-view-collapse-function)

Comment: Appears not to be possible in 10.4. If you right-click the panel and choose "Properties", you can see the settings you *can* make.

Comment: It doesn't retain what is expanded when switching between design/code/history so it wouldn't help much as everything would keep getting collapsed. These days I navigate code using [MMX](https://www.mmx-delphi.de/) (now free and maintained by Uwe Raabe) might be worth a look for you.